# gcc compiled binary in x86 assembly

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86

gcc compile binary has following assembly:

```
 8049264:   8d 44 24 3e             lea    0x3e(%esp),%eax          
 8049268:   89 c2                   mov    %eax,%edx                
 804926a:   bb ff 00 00 00          mov    $0xff,%ebx               
 804926f:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax                
 8049274:   89 d1                   mov    %edx,%ecx                
 8049276:   83 e1 02                and    $0x2,%ecx                
 8049279:   85 c9                   test   %ecx,%ecx
 804927b:   74 09                   je     0x8049286
```

At first glance, I had no idea what it is doing at all. My best guess is some sort of memory alignment and clearing up local variable (because rep stos is filling 0 at local variable location). If you take a look at first few lines, load address into eax and move to ecx and test if it is even address or not, but I'm lost why this is happening. I want to know what exactly happen in here.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like initialising a local variable located at [ESP + 0x03e] to zeroes.  At first, EDX is initialised to hold the address and EBX is initialised to hold the size in bytes.  Then, it's checked whether EDX & 2 is nonzero; in other words, whether EDX as a pointer is wyde-aligned but not tetra-aligned.  (Assuming ESP is tetrabyte aligned, as it generally should, EDX, which was initialised at 0x3E bytes above ESP, would not be tetrabyte aligned.  But this is slightly besides the point.)  If this is the case, the wyde from AX, which is zero, is stored at [EDX], EDX is incremented by two, and the counter EBX is decremented by two.  Now, assuming ESP was at least wyde-aligned, EDX is guaranteed to be tetra-aligned.  ECX is calculated to hold the number of tetrabytes remaining by shifting EBX right two bits, EDI is loaded from EDX, and the REP STOS stores that many zero tetrabytes at [EDI], incrementing EDI in the process.  Then, EDX is loaded from EDI to get the pointer-past-space-initialised-so-far.  Finally, if there were at least two bytes remaining uninitialised, a zero wyde is stored at [EDX] and EDX is incremented by two, and if there was at least one byte remaining uninitialised, a zero byte is stored at [EDX] and EDX is incremented by one.  The point of this extra complexity is apparently to store most of the zeroes as four-byte values rather than single-byte values, which may, under certain circumstances and in certain CPU architectures, be slightly faster.